# Change tracking in Entity Framework Core 2.0 changed my code behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

That code worked fine in Entity Framework 1.0 could also be 1.1.

```
var pupilFound = await context.Pupils.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == pupil.Id);
if (pupilFound == null)
{
    throw new BadDataException($"{nameof(pupil.Id)} is not valid");
}
if (pupilFound.UserId != userId)
{
    throw new NotAuthorizedException();
}

pupil.UserId = userId;
context.Entry(pupil).State = EntityState.Modified;
await contextSaveChangesAsync();
```

Now with Entity Framework Core 2.0 I got that exception with error:

```
Cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked
```

A quick fix would be:

```
var pupilFound = await context.Pupils.AsNoTracking.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == pupil.Id);
```

That way the tracking is disabled, but that defeats the purpose of the AsNoTracking method regarding the **official recommendation**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.querytrackingbehavior?view=efcore-2.0

```
Disabling change tracking is useful for read-only scenarios because it avoids
        //     the overhead of setting up change tracking for each entity instance. You should
        //     not disable change tracking if you want to manipulate entity instances and persist
        //     those changes to the database using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges
```

How else would update the pupil with all its properties coming from the client?

Comment: I can't imagine such code ever worked (in case there was not EF Core bug). `pupilFound` is the *"another instance of this type with the same key"* from the exception message.

Comment: Upvote for showing how to manually mark a record as modified. EF Core 2.0 wasn't picking up changes in a supposedly tracked record for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, it's highly unlikely that this code could run in the previous "beta" versions of EF-core (i.e. < v. 2). They were buggy, but not *that* bad.

Anyway, you're doing a lot there that could be less ceremonial.

First, anything related to authorization should be dealt with earlier in the processing pipeline by applying [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters), so you won't have to write this repetitive code time and again. But that's off-topic here. (Assuming that you're working in ASP.Net).

Secondly, on-topic, you really don't need to check whether the id exists in the database. Just attach the `pupil` object as modified and save changes. You have to catch exceptions anyway, so why not catch `DbUpdateException`s specifically, which will be thrown when the pupil has been deleted in the mean time (and other possible reasons).

Comment: To your offtopic Authorization comment => I did the 400/401 stuff already in filters but it resulted in more queries which I did not like. your ontopic comment is actually also offtopic because its related to the id_existance_check. This I do only for the validation. If I would attach it only without check id_existance I would still run into the same exception when I validate the pupil in a filter because the DbContext is per request defined and the filter would start tracking the pupil then in the repository just attaching the pupil I would still get that exception.

Comment: DbUpdateException can not happen here because if the user deletes his pupil he will not be able to update it. If he uses fiddler then the singleOrDefault will return the 400 bad data :-)

Comment: In a filter you could only check the UserId value without a db query. As for your second comment, that's only true if there are no concurrent users. And if so, why check the id anyway? In that case it can only be invalid if the user tampers with it in the request.

Comment: Not sure wether I understand you correct: "...check the UserId..." what is 'check' doing here if it does not need a db query? I need to prevent that any user with a legal UserId changes another user data. Thus every database action from anyone needs a sql interaction with the UserId. "...second comment...": There are no concurrent users for the same data. Every user is just reading/writing his own data. "...And if so...": RIGHT the check is just a protection due to tampering with fiddler.

Comment: In that case: just pull the pupil's UserId from the database, not the whole pupil object, so you'll have a light query. I just want to emphasize that cross-cutting concerns like authorization and exception handling (also deciding which http code to return) shouldn't be handled in action methods because it clutters the code, it's a source of inconsistency and it's error prone. In a project I work in db queries are needed for almost all authorization. No choice. The only choice was where to do them. We put them in the authorization pipeline.

Comment: I really understand your point and I agree that logging/exception_handling/security should be handled in a single class. But I already went the road with the action filters actually I used fluent validation - what is kind of its own filter - where I handled all the 400/401 stuff concerning the resourceId/UserId. But the more I faced complex Repo methods doing much database stuff the more I saw cumbersome code in the fluent validators. "Just pull the pupil`s UserId": That will not be sufficient to determine a 400 bad request you just get of it thats a not authorized request not more.